# Azure Databricks Unity Catalog: Accessing data located in ADSL

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have created a managed table and ingested some data using unity catalog path: `<my_catalog.my_schema.my_table>`.

I can see the data using data explorer in Databricks but when I try to read the file in my notebook with spark I get an error message:

`` `AnalysisException: [RequestId=3447b1d1-36a6-41c5-b5a9-09c34a7c74f7 ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE.LOCATION_OVERLAP] Input path url 'abfss://enriched@dlsdevlakehouse3o0r.dfs.core.windows.net/root/__unitystorage/catalogs/f96e5d08/tables/bbd6e7aa-acf9-90a6edd53749/tables/bb0a6edd53749' overlaps with managed storage within 'GenerateTemporaryPathCredential' call` ``

Can someone explain what is going on and how I can solve this?

Also, it is said that one should use managed table and not external table, why is that?

Comment: Can you share your code for creating the table and the code where access is attempted? It sounds like you are attempting to read the literal storage path instead of something like `spark.table("my_catalog.my_schema.my_table")`. See https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/unity-catalog/invalid_parameter_valuelocation_overlap-overlaps-with-managed-storage-error

Comment: I didn't use `spark.table("my_catalog.my_schema.my_table")`, I used instead `abfss://` but that is not possible with managed table if I have understood it correctly?

Comment: yes, it's not possible to access managed tables directly. But why are you trying to read it by path instead of by name? What is the reason?

Comment: I was just thinking what if I need to access the data in the future with some other software like airflow or ADF. How would I access the data then? It feels like one are constrained to Databricks with managed tables...